# How to determine the ports that a node app has opened

Tags: node.js, security, networking

While developing node ExpressJS apps I've seen example code that specifies that the server should listen on process.env.PORT || 80.  I understand this.  If the environment has a PORT set then the application choses that, and if not it uses port 80.  Since I configure the server, I have control over this and am aware of the ones I set.

However, it would still be useful to me to be able to access one of my servers and issue a command to see all running node apps and the ports they have opened.  **Is this possible**?

In part this is inspired by another issue, which is worrisome.   On my local machines, I run a port monitor for security and have noticed that my node apps make calls to external sites.  I haven't investigated it much, but I imagine it's becoming a thing now for modules and build tools to call home so their developers can gather usage metrics.   Not a huge problem during development, but if I could track the connections my node apps make, it would help identify packages used within them that may be serving as beacons of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Linux, you can do something like:

```
sudo netstat -nap | grep node
```

The -p option to print the process name is Linux specific. Another option is lsof. This should work on any system where lsof is installed:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -a -c node
```

Comment: Well that yielded some interesting information!  Exactly what I was needing.  Thank you.